# Filter out object by properties (not deleting)

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I have an object which looks like this:

```
var myObj: {
    2:"None",
    20:"A",
    31:"A",
    32:"A",
    Social:"B",
    Method:"None"
}
```

I am trying to return the object without the 'Social' and 'Method' properties.

First I tried deleting like this in a computed property, but it removes the properties from the main object:

```
props: ['myObj']

computed: {
     filterOut: {
        var myObject = this.myObj
        delete myVar['Social'];
        delete myVar['Method'];

        return myObject
    }
}
```

Then I tried using filter but it doesn't let me to do so:

```
      var myObject = this.myObj.filter(key => {
          return key != 'Method' || key != 'Social'
      })

      return myObject
```

> TypeError: this.myObj.filter is not a function

What is the best way of below object from above object?

```
var myObj: {
    2:"None",
    20:"A",
    31:"A",
    32:"A"
}
```

Comment: What's your goal? Why do you want the properties to remain but somehow not be visible? Can you simply clone the object and delete the properties on the clone?

Comment: @isherwood Your approach is yet the simplest and works. Basically, `Object.assign({}, this.myObj)`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Object.assign to create new object and then delete.

```js
var myObj =  {
    2:"None",
    20:"A",
    31:"A",
    32:"A",
    Social:"B",
    Method:"None"
};

var new_obj = Object.assign({},myObj); // or use spread operator {...myObj};


delete new_obj.Social;
delete new_obj.Method;

console.log(new_obj);
```

Comment: Perfectly valid, though note that deleting properties from an object tends to de-optimize it, making property access dramatically slower (in relative terms). Most of the time you don't care, though.

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a new object without those properties.

There's a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) for rest/spread properties that would let you do it this way:

```
const {Social, Method, ...newObj} = originalObj;
```

(Then just ignore the `Social` and `Method` constants.) But it's still just stage 3 (although it's nearing stage 4 and looks good to be in ES2018; it's supported without special flags in recent versions of both Chrome and Firefox).

Note that that will only handle *own, enumerable* properties.

In ES2015+ you could do it like this:

```
const newObj = {};
for (const key of Object.keys(originalObj)) {
    if (key != "Social" && key != "Method") {
        newObj[key] = originalObj[key];
    }
}
```

Or in ES5:

```
var newObj = {};
Object.keys(originalObj).forEach(function(key) {
    if (key != "Social" && key != "Method") {
        newObj[key] = originalObj[key];
    }
});
```

Those both also handle *own, enumerable* properties; if you want all own non-Symbol properties, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The function you want is [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a).

Try this something like this:

```
function deleteProperty(object, property) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj = obj || {};
    if (key !== property) {
      return { ...obj, [key]: object[key]};
    }
    return obj;
  })
}
```

You might need to do something like this if you're working in the browser or don't want to deal with babel. Do note the below is untested, the above is function tested and I use it almost everyday.

```
function deleteProperty(object, property) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj = obj || {};
    if (key !== property) {
      return Object.assign(obj, {[key]: object[key]});
    }
    return obj;
  })
}
```

Comment: How is the result of this different than the delete approach? (I'm not clear yet what OP wants, but....)

Comment: Well for starters, delete leaves a null reference and mutates the object in question. This creates a new object (no mutation) with only the desired properties (which is what OP wants, an object with specific properties removed). Just pretend javascript doesn't have a delete operator, it's useless @isherwood

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this, universal solution can help also:

```js
var myObj = {
    2: "None",
    20: "A",
    31: "A",
    32: "A",
    Social: "B",
    Method: "None"
}

var filtered = _.pickBy(myObj, (v,k)=> _.toInteger(k))

console.log(filtered)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash"></script>
```